# Docker jupyter 500: internal server error / Unknown exporter "ipynb"

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I am running jupyter/datascience-notebook:5811dcb711ba (the lastest one on 24 June).

Notebooks work. It is possible to enter commands and see the results.

However,
File > Download as > Notebook (.ipynb) 
gives a "500: Internal Server Error".

In the console there is a stack trace showing error in nbconvert,

> ```
>  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/base.py", line 110, in get_exporter
>    % (name, ', '.join(get_export_names())))
> ValueError: Unknown exporter "ipynb", did you mean one of: asciidoc, custom, html, latex, markdown, notebook, pdf, python, rst, script, slides?
> ```

This error happens on both linux and mac.

Answer (score 0):

This [PR fixed](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/pull/873) the problem for me. Not ideal but got tired of the error message;)

**UPDATE** My PR was merged so you can use the fix from nbconvert master branch or nbconvert >= 5.3.2 (when it gets released)